# Loop in data frames rows to create another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I've got the following data frame:

```
Loans <- data.frame(
     ID = c("215781","832567","721536"),
     From = c("01-01-2023","04-15-2022","09-23-2021"),
     End = c("05-02-2023","10-15-2023","12-23-2021"),
     Type = c("Monthly","Quarterly","Monthly"))
```

I need to create another data frame which has for every intra-period of each Loan a row with the ID and the Date, this loop that I've made isn't right but gets the idea of what I wanted to do. It works for 1 row if you delete the loop part

```
library(bizdays)

Base <- data.frame("TM",today())

colnames(Base) <- c("TM","InterestDates")



for (i in Loans[i,]){
  
  df <- as.data.frame(seq.Date(Loans$From,Loans$Until,by="month"))
colnames(df) <- "InterestDates"

    
df$TM <- Loans$TM

Base <- rbind(Base,df)


}
```

Something like this would be the expected output

```
ID     | InterestDates
250414 | 2022-05-16
250414 | 2022-06-16
250414 | 2022-07-18
250414 | 2022-08-16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm guessing you'd want something like this:

```
library(bizdays)

Loans <- data.frame(
  ID = c("215781","832567","721536"),
  From = c("01-01-2023","04-15-2022","09-23-2021"),
  End = c("05-02-2023","10-15-2023","12-23-2021"),
  Type = c("Monthly","Quarterly","Monthly"))

Base <- data.frame("ID" = character(),"InterestDates" = character())

Loans$From <- as.Date(Loans$From,format = "%m-%d-%y")
Loans$End <- as.Date(Loans$End,format = "%m-%d-%y")

for (i in 1:nrow(Loans)){
  
  if(Loans$Type[i] == "Monthly"){
    seq_dates <- seq.Date(Loans$From[i],Loans$End[i],by="month")
  }else if(Loans$Type[i] == "Quarterly"){
    seq_dates <- seq.Date(Loans$From[i],Loans$End[i],by="quarter")
  }

  df <- data.frame("ID" = rep(Loans$ID[i],length(seq_dates)),"InterestDates" = seq_dates)
  
  Base <- rbind(Base,df)
}
```

There's several issues in your original code.

- `Base <- data.frame("TM",today())` makes a dataframe already with one entry, not an empty dataframe
- The columns `From` and `End` of the `Loans` dataframe are not in `date` format that is necessary for the `seq.Date` command
- Loans does not have a column `TM`, but I'm guessing from your output, you want the `ID` column anyway
- `Loans[i,]` does not work since `i` does not exist - you cannot define `i` by `i`. Please look into how loops work in `R`
- The loop index is never used inside the loop. If you want the i-th entry of a column of a dataframe, access it via `Loans$From[i]`

Also I'm not quite sure: Do you want `by = "month"` for every entry of your original dataframe? Or dependent on the `Type` column of the `Loans` dataframe?

Comment: Hi KoL, first of all, thank you very much for your answer. Yeah sadly I´ve no clue about how Loops work and Im not good at all at writing questions in stack.  About your last point, yes, every entry should be dependent on the type column but I tried to avoid making the question more large and complex. Kind Regards!

Comment: Don't worry, we're all here to learn. Edited the code to include an if-else for the dependency on the type column. There are shorter ways to do it, but if you don't have too many different entries, this should do the trick. Feel free to ask if anything's unclear.